# How to write regex for finding the extensions of files

Tags: regex

I am trying to find the types of file extensions in a blob of text.

The file extensions are either followed by blank space or a special characters.
For example. ".txt 123" or ".xlsx-(123)". In these examples the texts I want to extract are txt and xlsx.

Note that extensions may contain either uppercase or lowercase letters (or both).

I have tried the following.

```
.[a-z]([-\s])
```

But it doesn't work. Please help me how to solve this problem.

Comment: txt and xlsx without the dot. However, I can remove the dot in the next step. Also txt and xlsx might not be the only extensions in the blob of text.

Comment: could be uppercase too.  [a-zA-Z] That's what I had written initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\.([a-zA-Z]+)[^A-Za-z]
```

- A dot is a metacharacter so it needs to be escaped (with the slash).
- The parentheses create a group.
- The character class `[a-zA-Z]` means any lowercase or uppercase letter.
- The `+` means one or more occurrences of the previous expression, hence `[a-zA-Z]+` means one or more letters.
- A `^` character as the first character in a character class means NOT. In other words `[^a-zA-Z]` means any character that is NOT a letter.

So the above expression looks for a [literal] dot followed by any number of lowercase or uppercase letters and finally followed by a non-letter (either lowercase or uppercase).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\b
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/PPhRkk/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-zA-Z0-9]+             any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z',
                           '0' to '9' (1 or more times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```